# phonegap (cordova) how to hide browser address bar

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm creating an ipad app using phoneGap (now cordova-1.8.0).  I can launch the app in ipad but the browser's address bar is always visible.  How do I get rid of address bar?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is being loaded in the app then you will never see the browser.

Is your app using local HTML or are you loading content from a remote server? I have a feeling you might be using content from a remote server. If that is the case make sure you add the server's host name to the whitelist. If the URL is not in the whitelist it will be opened in the browser.